# What is an attracting component subgraph?

Tags: python, networkx

What is a attracting component subgraph of a graph?

[Networkx has an algorithm for this.](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.attracting.attracting_component_subgraphs.html?highlight=subgraph#networkx.algorithms.components.attracting.attracting_component_subgraphs) But I am unable to understand what this is because:

```
>>> g.edges()
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
>>> for l in nx.algorithms.components.attracting.attracting_component_subgraphs(g):
...     print l.edges()
...     print l.nodes()
... 
[]
[4]
[]
[5]
```

Comment: from the answer by @DrewConway, it looks like if you reach 4/5 you cannot go anywhere else in the graph, thereby making them valid attracting components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of an attracting component is provided in the documentation for `nx.algorithms.components.attracting_components`.

> An attracting component in a directed graph  is a strongly connected
>   component with the property that a random walker on the graph will
>   never leave the component, once it enters the component.
>
> The nodes in attracting components can also be thought of as recurrent
>   nodes. If a random walker enters the attractor containing the node,
>   then the node will be visited infinitely often.

http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.attracting.attracting_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.attracting.attracting_components

Thus, an attracting component subgraph would be a list of nodes that induce subgraphs meeting this definition.